# CORS issue after initiating a redirect with Koa

Tags: vue.js, redirect, cors, koa2

I have an node.js app that uses the Koa framework and handles the auth flow for another app. I am trying to implement server-side redirects to appropriate pages on the client after the user logs in or out, but keep getting CORS errors.

I have the redirect set up as follows:

```
router.get('/logout', (ctx) => {
  ctx.status = 302;
  ctx.redirect('http://localhost:8080/login');
});
```

And I have CORS enabled server-side:

```
const corsOptions = {
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

However, after the client calls the endpoint and receives the redirect I get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3002/api/v2/logout') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Does anyone know how to properly solve this issue ?

Comment: The CORS configuration shown in the question is for which server? The `http://localhost:3002 ` server? Do you have CORS enabled on the `http://localhost:8080` server too?

Comment: The CORS configuration is on the koa app, which runs at `http://localhost:3002`. I have no such configuration on the client application (written in vue.js) so far.

Comment: You need to also CORS-enable the `http://localhost:8080` server. The error message cited in the question is specifically about the response from the `http://localhost:8080/login` having no Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this can be done. `http://localhost:8080/login` is just a login page on a vue.js dev server. I saw that I can set a dev server proxy to the same origin as the other app to bypass the CORS error, but in that case redirects don't work correctly because it's looking for `/login` at `http://localhost:3002` instead.